# How to delete the space between lines in a text file with awk?

Tags: awk

I would like to delete the space between lines in a text file using awk. How can I do this with awk?

```
abcd

abcd

abcd
```

The desired output would be

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NF' data.txt
```

will print out only non-blank lines from file `data.txt`. It works by only printing lines with the number of fields (`NF`) that are non-zero (i.e., greater than zero)

Alternatively,

```
awk 'length' data.txt
```

works by only printing out lines with length that is non-zero (i.e., greater than 0).

There are other tools, such as `sed` or `grep`, that can do this too, but since you specifically asked for an `awk` solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will output only non-blank lines

```
awk '/./' test.txt
```

This is an alternative unsing grep (matches empty lines, then invert results with -v):

```
grep -v ^$ test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite the input file, you can use `sponge`: [Is there a way to modify a file in-place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-p)

```
awk '/./ {print}' file | sponge file
```

Comment: `sponge` isn't part of my regular Ubuntu installation, is this something that needs to be installed extra? Just curious.

Comment: `sponge` is part of package `moreutils` .. it handles the overwrite in ways that are sometimes not handled so well, eg. *symbolic links*

Comment: Thanks for the info, sounds useful, I'll have to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps those lines have whitespace (only) (or not):

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*$/' inputfile
```

The same thing with `sed`:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' inputfile
```